# Icons for folders, programs are not what they should be, show as 'blank paper sheets'

Tags: icons

I'm new to Ubuntu and I ran into this problem. I have no idea how this happened and what caused it but now all the files look like this. As well as when I enter the software center all the icons there are the same default purple diamond.

[image]

[image]